# React Autocomplete with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm implementing a component Autocomplete using Material UI library.

But there's a problem - I'm not sure how to pass value and onChange properly, because I have a custom implementation of TextField that requires value and onChange as well. Should I pass value and onChange twice - to Autocomplete and TextField? Or maybe there's a better solution? Would appreciate any help!
Here's my code:

````
import { Autocomplete as MuiAutocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab'
import { FormControl } from 'components/_helpers/FormControl'
import { useStyles } from 'components/Select/styles'
import { Props as TextFieldProps, TextField } from 'components/TextField'

export type Props = Omit<TextFieldProps, 'children'> & {
  options: Array<any>
  value: string
  onChange: (value: string) => void

  disabled?: boolean
}

export const Autocomplete = (props: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <FormControl
      label={props.label}
      error={props.error}
      helperText={props.helperText}
    >
      <MuiAutocomplete
        options={props.options}
        // value={props.value}
        // onChange={event =>
        //   props.onChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as string)
        // }
        classes={{
          option: classes.menuItem,
        }}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
          />
        )}
        renderOption={option => {
          return <Typography>{option.label}</Typography>
        }}
      />
    </FormControl>
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Material UI has props built in to handle the state of the Autocomplete vs input values.

You can see it in use in the docs here: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states

In your example, you would want to add the `inputChange` and `onInputChange` props to the Autocomplete component. These will get passed down to your TextField through the params passed to the `renderInput` function.

So your final code would look something like the below snippet copied from the linked documentation:

```
<Autocomplete
  value={value}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  }}
  id="controllable-states-demo"
  options={options}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Comment: Great solution! Didnt know about the inputValue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete } from "@mui/material/node";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

 const valueFunc = (arr, id) => {
  const temp = arr.length > 0 && arr?.find((element) => element.id === id);
  return temp;
};

AutocompleteSearch.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf({
    title: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

export default function AutocompleteSearch({
  name,
  options,
  label,
  id,
  ...other
}) {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState({});
  const { control, setValue } = useFormContext();

  useEffect(async () => {
    const found = valueFunc(options, id);
    await setTemp(found);
  }, [options, id]);

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({ fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <>
          <div >
            <Autocomplete
              id="controllable-states-demo"
              onChange={(_, v) => {
                setValue(name, v?.id);
                setTemp(v);
              }}
              onBlur={(e) => {
                e.target.value == "" && setValue(name, "");
              }}
              value={temp}
              options={options}
              getOptionLabel={(item) => (item.title ? item.title : "")}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <>
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label={label}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      style: {
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        fontWeight: "400",
                        color: "#FF5B00",
                      },
                    }}
                 
                    size="small"
                    error={temp === null && !!error}
                    helperText={temp === null && error?.message}
                    {...other}
                  />
                </>
              )}
            />
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

```
 <AutocompleteSearch
   name="pharmacy_group_title"
   label="Pharmacy Group" 
   options={pharmacyGroups}                           // Array  {id , title}   
   id={defaultValues?.pharmacy_group_title}           // ID
  />
```